# Sorting structure of arrays with qsort

Tags: c, sorting, structure

Normally sorting Array of structure objects is easy. Consider an Array of a structure (AOS)

```
#define ITEMS 10

typedef struct MyStruct
{
 char a;
 int  b;
}tMyStruct;

tMyStruct arr_mystruct[ITEMS];
```

I first fill this array of structure with values of < a , b> pairs.

If I now want to sort this array of structures according to the integer field, I can do it using libc qsort function by using a comparison function which takes two integer arguments.

Now consider that I replace the above structure in AOS format with SOA format

```
#define ITEMS 10

typedef struct MyStruct
{
 char a[ITEMS];
 int  b[ITEMS];
}tMyStruct;

tMyStruct mystruct;
```

Now I can still use qsort to sort the array of integers b field, however this time I need to additionally sort a (array of characters)  w.r.t sorting order of b.

**So my question is what is a possible efficient way to do sorting for data laid out in SOA format instead of usual AOS format?**

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks!

Comment: `a w.r.t sorting order of b`. Can you please translate this one for me...

Comment: @AljoshaBre it means 'a with respect to sorting order of b'

Comment: I think he wants to sort the arrays `a` and `b` so that they are both sorted according to `b`'s data. In other words, keep all the pairs of data together.

Comment: You've tagged this with C++, are you interested in C++ solutions?  Ones that won't work in C?

Comment: If `std::sort` only works by means of `std::less` and `std::swap`, then you could solve your problem by providing a custom `std::swap` which takes care of `a`s as well. Otherwise there are really no "good" solutions.

Comment: Benjamin is correct. Example: <'a',10> , <'j', 3>, <'b', 4>. After sorting w.r.t b-field the order of objects would be: <'j', 3>, <'b', 4>, <'a',10>. I want to have the same sorting in SOA format i.e <'j,b,a', '3,4,10'>

Comment: benjamin, yes C++ solution would also be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use a helper array:

```
int helper[ITEMS];

int helper_cmp(const void *a, const void *b);

for (i = 0; i < ITEMS; ++i)
    helper[i] = i;
qsort(helper, ITEMS, sizeof(*helper), helper_cmp);
```

The `helper_cmp` function will take `helper` values as indices to `mystruct.b` and compares those values:

```
int helper_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int first = *(const int *)a;
    int second = *(const int *)b;
    int b_first = mystruct.b[first];
    int b_second = mystruct.b[second];
    // compare b_first and b_second
}
```

Then, after the `qsort`, the helper array will contain rearranged indices of `b`, telling how it should be ordered.

You can use this array to both rearrange `mystruct.a` and `mystruct.b`.

---

Note that this is not as efficient as sorting "array of struct". I don't know your application, but my guess is that "struct of array", in which the fields of the arrays are correlated is not a good idea in the first place. That is, if sorting of `b` affects sorting of `a`, they probably belong to the same conceptual element (call it class if you want), and it is better if they are grouped together in one `struct`.

Comment: SOA approach is frequently used optimization in multi-cores (SIMDization, cache efficiency) and GPU(CUDA).

Answer (score 0):

Other than the helper suggestion, there isn't a way to do this with qsort().  For a case like this, I would write my own sorting function.  For best balance of speed and easy-to-write I find that Insertion Sort works well for small arrays and Merge Sort works well for large arrays.